# Azure Active Directory API (token does not contain family_name and given_name)

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a problem with Azure Directory API. I am able to authorize and get a token from Azure AD service for both of my accounts. I have checked all settings on windowsazure.com page and for both accounts it looks the same.
I also use the same source code (Python + OAuth2Session + PyJWT) for both accounts.

Unfortunately for one account I get more details when I decode id_token. The problem is that I need get first_name and last_name fields, but it is possible only for one of them. Also I see that length of id_token is different for them (800 and 552 characters).

I use the following urls for authorize and get a token:

1. AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL: 'https://login.windows.net/%s/oauth2/authorize',
2. BASE_TOKEN_URL: 'https://login.windows.net/%s/oauth2/token',

Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Ok, I found out the reason why it does not work as i suspected. The API returns family_name and given_name only for the owner of Azure account. What can I do to return these data also for different users? Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible that the bigger token is for a user that is created in the Azure AD tenant (i.e. this user is authenticated by Azure AD), versus an MSA (Microsoft Account/LiveID) user?

Comment: hmm, both users are owners of Azure's account. One of them is able to authenticate on second user's web application using azure ad and then first_name is returned, but for second one it does not work properly - there is no first_name field. Generally i would like to allow to login in only users from my partner's company. if you could check my next question and tell something i would be very glad [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450734/how-can-i-use-users-from-my-partners-application-to-single-sign-on)