# How can i use users from my partner's application to single sign on

Tags: python, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to use Single Sign On based on users from ApplicationA to get in to ApplicationB? If yes how it should work in Azure AD portal and how should I use API to reach this goal?

Now I am able to authenticate users which have an account on Azure/Microsoft services, but I want to allow to get in to my application (ApplicationB) only users which are registered in my partner's application (ApplicationA).

I use OAuth2 protocol and python's libraries to handle all of this.

Comment: It seems like, as part of appB's authorization step, you want to check if the authenticated user is registered in AppA.  There may be some better ways to do this, maybe through claims, but you *could* make an oauth request to AppA (in the context of the signed in user), to find out if the user is registered in AppA, if AppA can expose an API for you to call.  If this sounds workable I can provide more details.

Comment: Could you tell me more about claims? How it works and where can i find good description about it? Sure, I'd be very glad if you could send me more details about second solution.

Comment: Before I answer - quick question.  Are the users always signed in to partner appA first, before signing in to appB - or could they come directly to appB too?

Comment: It is still considered, but we can assume that users always signed in to appA first, because my customer wants to public his business for free for users from appA. Maybe later it will be possible to log in directly in appB using accounts from appA, but now as i said we can assume that users always signed in to appA first.

Comment: Could you also describe how can I do itthrough claims? I have read a lot of documents, but most of them were destinated only for .NET and to be honest I have not found any helpful information about integration with partner.